# Is there a way to convert from a list of strings to an enum flag in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, enums, enum-flags

I have a list of strings in an xml document:

```
<properties>red yellow blue</properties>
```

and I have an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Properties 
{
    None    = 0,
    red = 1,
    yellow = 2,
    blue = 4,
    green = 8
}
```

Is there a way to convert the XML string into the enum flag value of `7` or `0111`?

There are countless resources around about doing the reverse of this, but I'm having trouble finding any information on converting from a string to Flags.

Comment: Are you asking to create a compile-time construct at runtime? You might be able to do this with reflection, but I'm sure there's probably an alternative to `enum`s here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you need them to be comma separated:

```
[Flags]
public enum Test
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4
}

Test t;
Enum.TryParse<Test>("A,B", out t);
```

Since you can't have spaces in the names, you can just do a string replace of space to comma before calling TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
string flags = "red yellow blue";

var eflags = flags.Split()
                  .Select(s => (Properties)Enum.Parse(typeof(Properties), s))
                  .Aggregate((a, e) => a | e);

Console.WriteLine(eflags);
Console.WriteLine((int)eflags);
```

Outpus

> red, yellow, blue
>
> 7

I'll leave how to get the string out of the xml up to you.

Comment: That's got to be the fastest down vote I've ever seen.

Comment: Apparently someone is on a down vote spree... I got one instantly too. Why do I even both with this site lol?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Now I've watched it go back and forth between an up vote and a down vote 3 or 4 times.  Kinda funny.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I am in need of so I don't understand the down-vote personally. Perhaps someone will chime in as to why this is a bad answer.

Comment: @leigero, if you look at my answer, Enum has this built in, so all this linq stuff is a bit over kill and a performance hit if you call repeatedly. Not sure if that was the reason... but randomly all the votes went to 0 lol. Might be a site bug or something.

Comment: @SledgeHammer It's not a bug, someone is voting and unvoting for some reason.